# How to use a virtual machine for building an enormous project?

Tags: ubuntu, build, virtual-machine

I'm on Ubuntu. I've downloaded a very large open source project which I want to build. This project can be built on Ubuntu but it requires thousands of dependencies to be downloaded. Ideally I would rather not have those in my Ubuntu.

Question: What tool could I use to have an OS inside my OS and download dependencies and build there?

Just to be clear, I know some people use VMs to automate builds. I don't need that level of sophistication.

EDIT: One answer mentioned KVM, Oracle VirtualBox, VMWare, and QEMU . Which on would be the more appropriate for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of softwares to create Virtual machines.

KVM, Oracle VirtualBox, VMWare,QEMU are some of the famous and easy to use and free versions are available.

Install any of above softwares, install ubuntu in VM using iso which is freely available.
Install dependencies in the VM, thus your Ubuntu will be free of dependencies. You can delete that VM whenever you want.

Comment: Where does Docker come into this? If at all.

Comment: What do you need docker for ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I have no idea. I just hear it's popular. But if you believe it has nothing to do with this, just ignore.

Comment: No, you don't need docker.

Comment: Edited my question. Of those that you mentioned, which one do you recommend for this? Are there even any differences at all?

Comment: No, you can use any of those.
I prefer Oracle Virtual Box, its simple and famous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153246/discussion-between-rathan-naik-and-oneloop).